# How to replace value in array using str_replace function in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, str-replace

I have a data as json format in  mysql database table as mentioned below.

```
 {
 "dataType": "mis_type",
 "diceCode": "20070100102",
 "forms": {
   "4. Campus": {},
   "7. Classroom": {},
   "1. Details of school": {
          "School_Name": "GOVT. UPG .M.S. KHAGARA",
          "Village_Name": "KHAGARA",
          "Block_Name": "MOHAN PUR",
          "Dist_Name": "DEOGHAR",
          "Type_of_School": "DEPARTMENT OF EDUCATION",
          "Category": "PRIMARY WITH UPPER PRIMARY",
          "No_of_Student": 209,
          "No_of_Section": 8,
          "No_of_Classroom": 5,
          "Govt_Teacher": 2,
          "Para_Teacher": 3,
          "Other_Teacher": 0,
          "Total_Teacher": 5,
          "Total_Toilet": 2,
          "Total_Urinals": 2
             },
    "6. Drinking Water Source": {},
    "8. Kitchen Shed": {},
    "2. Location of School": {},
    "5. Location of Toilet": {},
    "3. Pollution Status": {
    }
   }
 }
```

I am trying to replace “ Total_Toilet ” value from another new value .  For that I wrote following code.

```
  $selectQuery = "SELECT `json_data` FROM `abc` WHERE `disc_code`='" . $diseCode . "' AND `type`='mis'";
  $res = $conn->query($selectQuery);
  $jsonvalue = $res->fetch_assoc();
  $jsonvalue = json_decode($jsonvalue['json_data'], true);
  unset($value['Dise_Code']);
  unset($value['OBJECTID']);
  if ($res->num_rows > 0) 
 {
   foreach( $jsonvalue['forms']['1. Details of school'] as $key1 => $value1 )
 {
   echo"<br>"; 
   $key2 = str_replace($jsonvalue['forms']['1. Details of school'] ['Total_Toilet'] , 4, $value1 ) ;
   echo $key2;
 }
```

The code is being compiled without any error but still the previous value is not getting replaced by the new value using str_replace function. 
If there is something wrong I am doing then please guide me or if any alternative solution anyone know please help me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is value of $value1  in foreach

Comment: and what you need as output?

Comment: I am getting all values of  "Details of School" object in $value1 variable. The values you can see in the json as I posted above.

Comment: As you can see in the json data Total_Toilet having value 2 which I want to replace by 4 . I also mentioned in str_repalce function.

Comment: but what output you need. you have used str_replace and please check str_replace function man page

Comment: Hey ...Lokesh  I know how str_replace function work . I want to see Total_Toilet value as 4 which I put in the str_replace function as replace a value.

Answer (score 1):

Ok please add below line before foreach loop

```
$jsonvalue['forms']['1. Details of school']['Total_Toilet'] = 4;
```

And make the foreach loop as below

```
foreach( $jsonvalue['forms']['1. Details of school'] as $key1 => $value1)
{
    echo"<br>"; 
    $key2 = $value1;
    echo $key2;
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for comment ... By mistake I posted syntax error I am using same as you suggested.

Comment: I have editted my answer so please try it @MayankSoni

Comment: I am able to get Total_Toilet value which is coming from mysql database. but I am thinking still problem is remain in the str_replace function which is not able to find Total_Toilet key inside passed $value1 array.

Comment: You changed the foreach loop as i editted in my answer ?

Comment: Actually according to me there is no need of str_replace , just try as I suggested. Just add that line just above foreach and change the foreach loop as I suggested in answer. Just give it try @MayankSoni :)

Comment: I modified code as you suggested now Total_Toilet is show is showing value 4 but still it is not getting replaced from new value.

Comment: You need the total_values as 4 right so now it is coming 4 so exactly what you want as output @MayankSoni?

Comment: There are 487000 records in mysql database those I want update by new data that why I am using str_replace function. The new data that need be updated I am taking from a json file. So the solution you suggested is not feasible as per my requirement  I think soo.

Comment: Means you need to update in the mysql database , only for Total_Toilet ? If yes then I think you should fire update query for that. Isn't it ?

Comment: I want to update Total_Toilet values by new values which is coming from json file. Total  Total_Toilet values are 15779 .

Comment: Can you tell me where you are fetching the new json file values in your code? I mean to say did you code to fetch new Total_Toilet from new json file that you want to update with old one of database.

Comment: Hi ..@Mahamadali  , I created an array **jsondata** and I decoded all json data in that array. Like that :  `$jsondata = json_decode($jsondata , TRUE);`  After that through foreach loop I am fetching json data in $value.                                                                                                        `foreach ($jsondata as $key =>$value) { $diseCode =$value['Dise_Code'];
$total_toilet = $value['Total Toilet'];  }` here I am getting new total_toilet values those  values I want replace by previous values.

Comment: Ok then , Can you please try my below answer , just replace the $new_value with the value from json file.

Comment: Ya I tried. It is getting compiled without any error but still output is nothing. nothing is displaying.

Comment: After the execution it will update in your database , please check wether in your db its updated or not ?

Comment: I didn't do for database. Actually I tried to display replaced value on browser.  ok..........I will do for database as well.

Comment: For displaying on browser please check my editted answer at below, it will print new json with new value on browser.Please try and let me know.

Comment: It didn't worked out ...I am not getting any output on browser . even I tried for database unfortunately  it deleted json data form table.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your foreach loop as below to update your database

```
foreach($jsonvalue['forms']['1. Details of school'] as $key1 => $value1 )
{
   $current_value = $jsonvalue['forms']['1. Details of school']['Total_Toilet'];
   $new_value = '12'; // Replace with new value that you want
   echo $new_json = str_replace('"Total_Toilet": '.$current_value.'','"Total_Toilet": '.$new_value.'',$jsonvalue['json_data']);
   echo "<hr>";
   $updateQuery = "update `abc` set `json_data` = '".$new_json."' WHERE `disc_code`='" . $diseCode . "' AND `type`='mis'";
   $res = $conn->query($updateQuery);
}
```

Note : Edit the variables in the query as per your requirements.Feel free to comment.